# Всем атрибутам массива объекта присваиваются одинаковые значения

Tags: java, массивы

У всех элементов массива атрибуты становятся одинаковые, если выполнить метод `AddValueForObject`.

Например, если при первом вводе введены значения: `obj[1].width=1` и `obj[1].length=1;`, то при втором вводе изменятся не только `obj[2].width` и `obj[2].length`, но и первые элементы массива: `obj[1].width obj[1].length`.

Помогите пожалуйста. Три дня голову ломаю.

Думал, что мб из-за использования `static`?

```
package MainProject;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Objects {
public static int objNumbet = 0;
public static float width = 0;
public static float length = 0;
public  static float area = 0;
public  static String jlab;
public static   Objects[] Obj = new Objects[100];

//public static Object[] Obj;

public static void AddValueForObject() {

    if (Main2.textField_1.getText().length() != 0 && Main2.textField_2.getText().length() != 0 && !Main2.textField_2.getText().equals("0") && !Main2.textField_1.getText().equals("0")) {
        AmountObj.amount += 1;
        //MainProject.Objects[] Obj = new MainProject.Objects[100];
        //Objects[] Obj = new Objects[AmountObj.amount];
        Obj[AmountObj.amount] = new Objects();
        System.out.println(Main2.textField_1.getText());
        System.out.println(Main2.textField_2.getText());
        //Obj[AmountObj.amount] = new Objects();
        //Вот тут считываются значения с полей
        Obj[AmountObj.amount].width = Float.parseFloat(Main2.textField_1.getText());
        Obj[AmountObj.amount].length = Float.parseFloat(Main2.textField_2.getText());
        Obj[AmountObj.amount].objNumbet = AmountObj.amount;
        Obj[AmountObj.amount].area = Float.parseFloat(Main2.textField_1.getText())* Float.parseFloat(Main2.textField_2.getText());

        Main2.textField_1.setText("0");
        Main2.textField_2.setText("0");
        FillTextF4();
    }else {
        FillTextF4();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выясните, что значит ключевое слово `static`.

```
public /*static*/ int objNumbet = 0;
public /*static*/ float width = 0;
public /*static*/ float length = 0;
public /*static*/ float area = 0;
public /*static*/ String jlab;
```

Comment: @InSpaceGame На здоровье. Успехов!